# Delete a database entry not working

Tags: php

I have two pages, the first shows all items from a particular field in a MySQL database:

**DatabaseEntries.php**

```
<?php
include('connect.php');

$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM names") 
    or die(mysqli_error($db));  


echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
echo "<tr> <th>Firstname</th> <th>lastname</th> <th>Email</th><th></th> ";


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )) {

    // echo out the contents of each row into a table

    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td>' . $row['firstname'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['lastname'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['email'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td><a href="delete.php?email=' . $row['email'] . '">Delete</a></td>';
    echo "</tr>"; 

} 
?>
```

the second page contains the delete function:

**Delete.php**

```
 <?php

 include('connect.php');

 // check if the 'id' variable is set in URL, and check that it is valid
 if (isset($_GET['email']) )
 {
 // get id value
 $email = $_GET['email'];

 // delete the entry
 $result = mysqli_query($db, "DELETE FROM names WHERE email=$email")
 or die(mysqli_error($db)); 

 // redirect back to the view page
 header("Location: DatabaseEntries.php");
 }
 else
 // if id isn't set, or isn't valid, redirect back to view page
 {
 header("Location: Error.php");
 }

?>
```

I get the following error when trying to delete an item from the database:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com' at line 1
```

Can anyone tell me why? and what to do to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: you have an error near **$email** in delete command; add single quote, try this `DELETE FROM names WHERE email = '$email'`

Comment: Your code is *wide open* to **SQL injection attacks**.  Technically you don't control the syntax of your SQL statement, you're just executing whatever code the user sends you.

Comment: @David where is it open to SQL injection at all?

Comment: @oggle0901: In your `DELETE` statement where you directly apply user input to your executable SQL code.

Comment: its a delete button, how could this do anything..

Comment: @oggle0901 - it's not a button, it's a hyperlink. It's trivial to change the text of the link to pass in arbitrary SQL instead of what you assume is going to be submitted. It's slightly more difficult to change the input of a form, but anyone who can access the DOM of the page can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `quotes` around the `$email`

```
DELETE FROM names WHERE email='$email'
```